# Using python 3.10, but pylance still says "alternative syntax for unions requires python 3.10 or newer?"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I just upgraded python to 3.10 for the new features, and when I do import sys; sys.version using the ipython console in vs code, it prints python version 3.10.0. But when I open an editor window and try to enter a type annotation using | for sum types, eg x:int|float, pylance highlights the | and says "alternative syntax for unions requires python 3.10 or newer."

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the interpreter for your VS Code ? Note, it is important to understand, one does not "upgrade" interpreters, you downloaded an installed a completely seperate interpreter/runtime

Answer (score 5):

VS Code may be using a different version of python.  Make sure that the default python interpreter  (under settings, search for python) is python3.10
(if you are using linux, /usr/bin/python3.10 will probably work)

Answer (score 1):

The "dmypy" is the daemon handles all the type checking process. As you type the commad "ps ax | grep dmypy" to the console, you'll see which version of python is executing it.

The "mypy.runUsingActiveInterpreter" is the setting to use the active Python interpreter or not. After enabling the "mypy.runUsingActiveInterpreter", it starts by the Python Interpreter accordingly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my operating system is Ubutnu18.04. The condition might not the same as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this exact problem on VS Code even though my python interpreter was properly set to v3.9.18 (as confirmed by `python --version`). The solution was to add the following import at the top of my python file:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

Comment: This is a different but related issue - this solves it if your interpreter is indeed < 3.10. The OP needs to change the VS Code interpreter to something 3.10+

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use "python3" in "Default Interpreter Path". In my case, I noticed that terminal didn't recognize the command "python", but there was "python3" command, which comes with Python v3 and up. So I changed the path to that and I didn't get any errors anymore.

[image: Python Default Interpreter Path]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is import this below line into the top of your file.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```